# Top Answerers for a tag calculated how?

Tags: discussion

There are lists of top users per tag e.g. [Android tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/topusers)

How is that reputation calculated wrt these lists?

---

Here is the list of top answerers Android over the last 30 days:

[image: < picture >]

- CommonsWare has provided 213 answers - that seems quite simple.
- From those, he has scored 199 reputation - this number does not make sense to me.

I would have thought that any reputation earned from any answer that has been tagged `Android` would contribute to this score.

However that does not seem to be the case - my score on the list is 18 which does not add up that way:

- are bounties included?
- is reputation on older answers included?
- is the reputation from tagged answers averaged across the tags? i.e. 10 rep on an answer with 2 tags means 5 rep per tag?

What other factors go into this calculation? I would like to understand how these lists are created.

Comment: It's not reputation. It's score (upvotes - downvotes)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hover over the number on the left and you'll find that it's "Total score of ...". So it's not reputation that's displayed, but the score achieved, i.e. upvotes - downvotes.

Comment: I see the word "score" but didn't realise its meaning. Thx for quick response.